# No "Sun Position" Addon in my Blender 2.8 on MAC

Tags: add-on

In my Blender 2.8 on my Mac is the "SunPosition" addon missing. When I go to Preferences-Addons I am not able to choose and tick it on. On my PC it works fine and Iam able to use it.

I researched the Internet now for some time but seems that I cannot find an answer to that.

Comment: Try to download a more recent version. I think it has been re-added since the official 2.80 launch https://www.blender.org/download/

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you select `Community` Addons (FYI, I am on 2.83.8):

[image]

Comment: Hi Bruno .. thx so much for your help. Unfortunately its not appering in my Blender. :( in the way you showed.. Must be my Programm. I try to get a newer version . thnaks again. //Daniel